# Jena Fuseki server in EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, jena, fuseki

I installed Jena Fuseki Server in my EC2 instance.
Its working good.
When i am trying to add the dataset, it doesn't show the option to add dataset.
What is the issue with dataset location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the security on the UI is set to respond to change operations only if the request comes from "localhost".

See the file `shiro.ini` for instructions on how to set Fuseki to use user/password authentication.

http://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-security.html